# Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input' in submodule in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several submodules in my project, one of them, is the SharedModule (which shares the modules in common for all).

The SharedModule includes the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule import.
I import this module into the module that I want to use the forms, but it doesn't work.

**Component template chunk**

```
<div class="md-form">
<input [formControl]="personGroup.get('medication')" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" mdbActive type="text" id="medication" class="form-control" #medication>
<label for="medication" class="">Ingrese el medicamento</label>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="addMedication(medication.value)">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

**SubModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [    
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class PeopleModule { }
```

**The SharedModule**

```
 import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     ...
     FormsModule, 
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     ...
   ],
   exports: [
     ...
     FormsModule, 
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     ...
   ],
   declarations: [
     ...
   ],
   schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
 })
 export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried.

Comment: Does binding to `[ngModel]` without `ngModelOptions` work?

Comment: @ConnorsFan ngModel works, ngModelOptions doesn't. I don't know if I actually forget something import or config.

Comment: Which version of Angular do you use? Please show the code where you use `ngModelOptions`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm using Angular 5.2.10, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to use `ngModelOptions`, the `ngModel` directive should be applied to the input element:

```
<input ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ... />
```

because `ngModelOptions` is a property of the `ngModel` directive.

Comment: i needed both  [(ngModel)]="location.value"
                                    [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" and removed formControlName="location"