# Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input' in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, antd, ng-zorro-antd

Here is my HTML:

```html
<nz-form-item nzFlex [formGroup]="hulkForm">
   <nz-form-label [nzSpan]="7" [nzFor]="hulkColumn.column" 
        [nzRequired]="hulkColumn.require">{{hulkColumn.lable}}</nz-form-label>
   <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="17">
   <input nz-input 
       placeholder={{hulkColumn.placeholder}} 
       [formControlName]="hulkColumn.name"
       [(ngModel)]="hulkColumn.model"
     [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
     name="{{hulkColumn.name}}"
        *ngIf="hulkColumn.type!=='number'"
       >
 </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

Here is the error in Chrome:

[image]

Here is app.module.ts:

```ts
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgZorroAntdModule, NZ_I18N, zh_CN} from 'ng-zorro-antd';
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
import zh from '@angular/common/locales/zh';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


registerLocaleData(zh);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
  ...
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ...
  ],
  providers: [{provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: zh_CN}, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}, CheckLoginGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I'm using the following:

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 8.9.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.7
NG-ZORRO-ANTD
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input' in submodule in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081189/cant-bind-to-ngmodeloptions-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input-in-sub)

Comment: Better you share the html and ts code.

Comment: <input nz-input 
        placeholder={{hulkColumn.placeholder}} 
        [formControlName]="hulkColumn.name"
        [(ngModel)]="hulkColumn.model"
         [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
         name="{{hulkColumn.name}}"
      *ngIf="hulkColumn.type!=='number'"
        >

Answer (score 5):

You need to import **FormsModule** in **app.component.ts** file

Steps:

1. Open app.module.ts
2. Add the following import statement

   ```
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   ```
3. Add FormsModule in imports @NgModule

   ```
   @NgModule({ imports: [ FormsModule ], })
   ```

Final code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; //----<<< Adding Import Statement
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule, 
  FormsModule //-------<< Import here
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: aleady add this

Answer (score 2):

You have to also import ReactiveFormsModule.

That will work.

```
@NgModule({ imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ] })
```

Comment: Try adding like this : <input ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ... />. In order to use ngModelOptions, the ngModel directive should be applied to the input element

Answer (score 2):

You missed to import the CommonModule of angular which provides ngmodel related structural directives.

Updating the above answer:

You are mixing the reactive forms and template forms.
Please remove [formControlName]  property as we cannot use FormsModule and ReactiveForms together

if you remove the above it works fine.
You can see the below stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-setup-juf9hp

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is the absence of *ReactiveFormsModule* in the *imports* section of the *standalone* component. That component in questions have a mixed form, join some things from *Template Drive Form* and *Reactive Forms*. The Forms modules had already imported but the Reactive Form module aren't. The solution is the act of import the two modules at same time, like I did, see the image.

In my case, was needed add a line of import in the top of component and de module in the imports section of component. Like the image shows.

Code for refence:

```
import { FormsModule, FormControl, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

imports: [MatIconModule, NgIf, MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatButtonModule,
MatTableModule, MatSortModule, MatDialogModule, MatPaginatorModule]

[image: Problem solved after addition of ReactiveFormsModule]

More code for make easy search and reference:

```
import { FormsModule, FormControl, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
... Other imports ...
import { ViewChild, TemplateRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit,
   OnInit, Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dominio',
    templateUrl: './dominio.component.html',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MatIconModule, NgIf, MatFormFieldModule,
       MatInputModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatButtonModule,
       MatTableModule, MatSortModule, MatDialogModule, MatPaginatorModule]
})
export class DominioComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
```